# how to make a list of lists with difference between lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of some numbers:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and another one:

```
l2 = [3,5,6]
```

I wanna get the list of intervals with numbers which exist are in the l2, but not in l1:

```
intervals = [[1,2],[4],[7]]
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
current_common_line_no = 0
    for line in l1:
        if line in l2:
            current_common_line_no = line
        else:
            next_common_line_no = l2[(l2.index(current_common_line_no))+1]
            print next_common_line_no
```

to get list of interval edges, but what next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` with list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby    
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(l1, key=lambda x: x not in l2) if k]
# [[1, 2], [4], [7]]
```

Comment: Nice. `groupby` is full of surprising uses.

Answer (score -1):

Use sets. Python has built in set data structures. What you are looking for is difference. Here is the documentation.

So set.difference(x,y)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Let me know if you need more than this

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know about sets, but difference() don't help to find intervals.%)

Comment: Seems groupby is what you are looking for!